# Decodable conformance with other protocols in Swift

Tags: swift, protocols, codable, decodable

The issue is when a struct conforms to a protocol (let's call it PA) and Decodable, but PA imposes a property with a type that is not Decodable. Example:

```
protocol PA {
    var b: [PB]? { get }
}

protocol PB {}

struct SA: PA, Decodable {
    let b: [PB]? // SA's conformance to Decodable wants this to be [Decodable], but PA's conformance imposes [PB]
}

struct SB: PB, Decodable {}
```

the code above refuses to compile, with:

- error: type 'SA' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
- note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[PB]?' does not conform to 'Decodable'

Changing that line to:

```
let b: [PB & Decodable]?
```

does not work either and gives:

- error: type 'SA' does not conform to protocol 'PA'
- note: candidate has non-matching type '[Decodable & PB]?'
- error: type 'SA' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'
- note: cannot automatically synthesize 'Decodable' because '[Decodable & PB]?' does not conform to 'Decodable'
- note: protocol requires property 'b' with type '[PB]?'; do you want to add a stub?

Note that the 4th line is non-sense: "'[Decodable & PB]?' does not conform to 'Decodable'". Wait what?

Any suggestion?

Comment: The obvious solution is to make PB conform to Decodable ,why can't you do that? And if PB can't conform to Decodable then what is it you want to decode?

Answer (score 1):

You may create a mixed protocol:

```
protocol PADecodable {
    var b: [PB & Decodable]? { get }
}

struct SA: PADecodable {
    let b: [PB & Decodable]?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can fix it by:

```
protocol PA {
    var b: [PB]? { get }
}

protocol PB {}

struct SA<T: PB & Codable>: PA, Codable {
    private var _b: [T]?
    
    var b: [PB]? {
        return _b
    }
}
```

Comment: True, it would work. I was hoping to avoid using a private property though.